# Python/Jupyter doesn't recognize cpython-39-darwin.so files

Tags: python, cpython, .so, open3d

I'm trying to import modules ending in `cpython-39-darwin.so` and python doesn't recognize them. When I remove `cpython-39-darwin` and just leave `.so`, my program can recognize them, but then it raises an error about 'incompatible architecture'. I noticed this issue when trying to import open3d, but it's happening with other libraries too.

I have a new MacBook (M1 Pro) and I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the issue.

`import open3d`

---

`ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)`
`Input In [26], in <cell line: 1>()`
`----> 1 import open3d`

`File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/open3d/`**`init`**`.py:90, in <module>`

`84         warnings.warn(`

`85             "Open3D was built with CUDA support, but Open3D CUDA Python "`

`86             "binding library not found! Falling back to the CPU Python "`

`87             "binding library.", ImportWarning)`

`89 if`**`DEVICE_API`** `== 'cpu':`

`---> 90     from open3d.cpu.pybind import (camera, data, geometry, io, pipelines,`

`91                                    utility, t)`

`92     from open3d.cpu import pybind`

`94 import open3d.core`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'open3d.cpu.pybind'`

The file itself is in `/open3d/cpu/pybind.cpython-39-darwin.so`. When I change it to `/open3d/cpu/pybind.so`, it recognizes the file, but now I get the following error:

---

`ImportError`

`...`

`(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/pybind.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/pybind.so' (no such file)`

Comment: May, I tooo am desparately seeking solutions for this problem. still no luck. But if you have already got one, then please update.

Comment: Same problem here